# what's the meaning of "-mathlink" as part of Arg for LinkLaunch?

Tags: programming, mathlink-or-wstp, kernel, kernel-startup

```
LinkLaunch["MathKernel -mathlink"]
LinkLaunch["MathKernel"]
```

The both code line above can launch a MathKernel. What's the difference of them? what's the meaning of "-mathlink"?

Answer (score 3):

The [legacy documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v9/ref/program/MathKernel.html) says:

[image]

In version 10 MathLink was replaced with [WSTP](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WSTPAPI.html).  The equivalent flag is now `-wstp`.

---

If I run `MathKernel.exe` from the command line without any flags I get this:

[image]

However if I run `MathKernel.exe -wstp` (equivalent to the old `-mathlink` flag I believe) I get only:

[image]

Comment: Except mathlink, we can set it to communicate via something else?

Comment: @yyteen I assume the command line interface.

Comment: but if I cut the "-mathlink" off, it is also worked. Is there any difference?

Comment: @yyteen I added screen captures of the behavior I observe.  I am not sure what further answer you are looking for.

Comment: I don't know how it will be acting in MMA10. But in MMA8, either `LinkLaunch["MathKernel"]` or `LinkLaunch[MathKernel -mathlink]` are the same. It seems no difference.